# quality issue with offline voice-to-text using Sphinx4

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'd like to perform voice recognition on a large number of `.wav` files that are continually being generated.

There are a growing number of online voice-to-text API services (e.g. [Google Cloud Speech](https://cloud.google.com/speech), [Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex), [Twilio Speech Recognition](https://www.twilio.com/speech-recognition), [Nexmo Voice](https://www.nexmo.com/products/voice), etc.) which would work well for connected applications, but aren't suitable for this use case due to cost and bandwidth.

A quick google search suggested [CMUSphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/) (CMU = Carnegie Mellon University) is popular for speech recognition.

I tried the 'hello world' example:

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

        StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/test.wav"));

        recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
        SpeechResult result;
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
        }
        recognizer.stopRecognition();

    }
}
```

The result was slightly disappointing. The '[test.wav](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/tree/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/speakerid/test.wav)' file contains the following audio:

> This is the first interval of speaking. After the first moment of
>   silent, this is the second interval of speaking. After the third
>   moment of silence, this the third interval of speaking and the last
>   one.

This was interpreted as:

> this is the first interval speaking ... for the first moment of
>   silence is the second of all speaking ... for the for the moment of
>   silence this is the f***ing several speaking in the last

Most of the words have been captured, but the output is garbled to the extent that the meaning is lost. I then downloaded a news story where the enunciation was crystal clear, and the transcription was complete gibberish. It captured as much as a very drunk person would listening to a foreign language.

I'm curious to know if anyone's using Sphinx4 successfully and, if so, what tweaks were done to make it work? Are there alternative acoustic/language models, dictionaries etc... that perform better? Any other open source suggestions for offline speech-to-text I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a trivial issue that's documented in the FAQ: "[Q: What is sample rate and how does it affect accuracy](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-what-is-sample-rate-and-how-does-it-affect-accuracy)"

> [...] we can not detect sample rate yet. So before using decoder you
>   need to make sure that both sample rate of the decoder matches the
>   sample rate of the input audio and the bandwidth of the audio matches
>   the bandwidth that was used to train the model. A mismatch results in
>   very bad accuracy.

The news footage was BBC audio stereo, recorded at 44.1 khz.

```
$ soxi GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisin.wav

Input File     : 'GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisin.wav'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:29:23.79 = 77783087 samples = 132284 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 311M
Bit Rate       : 1.41M
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

I converted it to mono:

```
$ sox GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisin.wav GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono.wav remix 1,2
$ soxi GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono.wav

Input File     : 'GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:29:23.79 = 77783087 samples = 132284 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 156M
Bit Rate       : 706k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Then downsampled to 16khz:

```
$ sox GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono.wav -r 16k GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono16k.wav
$ soxi GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono16k.wav

Input File     : 'GlobalNewsPodcast-20170828-CatastrophicFloodsRisinMono16k.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:29:23.79 = 28220621 samples ~ 132284 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 56.4M
Bit Rate       : 256k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Now it's working pretty well. Here's a snippet of transcribed audio from the news article:

> emergency officials said they expect the hall from million people to
>   seek assistance in texas bolton flashy thousand people already being
>   cared for in temporary shelter is on the engine is a big on releasing
>   water from two downs that protect houston city sense of ...